# Displaying variable label instead of variable names

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, label

Is there a way to display variable labels in a dataframe instead of variable names ?

A little piece of code to illustrate my idea :

```
df <- data.frame("a"=c(1,2,3),"b"=c(4,5,6),"c"=c(7,8,9))

label(df[,"a"]) <- "my_a"
label(df[,"b"]) <- "my_b"
label(df[,"c"]) <- "my_c"

ui <- pageWithSidebar(

 # App title ----
  headerPanel("TEST"),

 # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
  sidebarPanel(),

 # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  mainPanel(
  tableOutput("base")
 )
)

server <- function(output,input){
 output$base <- renderTable(print(df))
 }


shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

I would like  the first line of my datatable in the app to be "my_a",my_b","my_c" instead of "a","b","c" (but keep the column names unchanged)

Comment: so, you want to display one thing but keep the old one. Then why not make another dataframe with columns names changed and use the other one to make your functions etc.?

Comment: To change the column name u just can do : `names(df)[1] <- "my_a"`

Comment: Actually, this is the only solution I found, but I was wondering if there was a way to do that without creating two dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `renderTable` call as follows:

```
output$base <- renderTable(as.data.frame(as.list(df), col.names = label(df)))
```

This actually creates a new dataframe with different column headings, but it's only a temporary object, so you don't need to worry about it getting out of sync with the real one.

Comment: Wonderful !
I think this can solve my problem. Thanks :)